# Login - Grafana With Angular+SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, grafana

I am using Angular with Springboot for Application and using JWT token for  authentication.
I am evaluation Grafana for Reporting Purpose but my Problem is How Can I Login automatically from Angular link to Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use some JWT. But use Single Sign On (SSO) protocol - Open ID Connect (OIDC) for both implementations. Users will be logged in automatically, when you have proper SSO implementations and they will be connecting to the same identity provider (IDP) server.

Comment: We have only mysql db which we are using for springboot. How can I implement SSO?

Comment: @Sanjay https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth

Comment: Current springboot already using JWT token. Is that possible with that?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a chat.